# Database configuration in Django

Tags: django, database, settings

How do I use a database connection URL in setting up database config in Django as opposed to using a dictionary?
Instead of using:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.getenv('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.getenv('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'PORT': os.getenv('DB_PORT'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('DB_HOST')
     }
 }
```

I want to use:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgresql://DB_USER:DB_PASSWORD@localhost:5432/DB_NAME'
     }
 }
```

Comment: There is no default way to do this, someone made [dj-database-url](https://pypi.org/project/dj-database-url/) which allows you to do exactly this.

Comment: Thank you Nico Griffioen. I will check out dj-database-url

Answer (score 1):

This is how I added a **database url** to one of my django apps.

*First*, install [this package](https://github.com/jacobian/dj-database-url#installation)

```
pip install dj-database-url
```

*Next*, add this line to your **`settings.py`** in your **django project**

```py
...
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(default=os.getenv('DATABASE_URI'))
...
```

*In place of `os.getenv('DATABASE_URI')`, you can also explicitly mention your database url*

You can refer [here to the github repo](https://github.com/jacobian/dj-database-url#usage) for more configurations.